# Cordova application scrolls when keyboard is open on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

I am currently building a web application based on Cordova.

When the user decide to focus on a textbox and the keyboard opens, the whole application is scrolling up, including the background and all fixed elements.

On the example below, the background is applied on the html tag, and the logo is position fixed.

```
html {
    background: url('background.jpg') center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    top: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Is there a way with a web-based cordova application, when the keyboard opens to only move the form to the top, without moving the background, neither the logo?

I would like the keyboard to shrink the view, resize it to something smaller instead of pushing it up with a scrollbar on the right.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [keyboard plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard) for this. Install the plugin and then set this preference in your config.xml file.

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
```

It works by shrinking the webview to just the space above the keyboard, so this should give you the behavior you describe.

Comment: Works great in the Android InAppBrowser but I can't get it to work in the iOS InAppBrowser. Do you know if that settings should work in the InAppBrowser?

Comment: Android has the `KeyboardShrinksView` behavior by default for all webviews. This plugin only adds the behavior to the main webview on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

**KeyboardShrinksView ** doesn't work in iOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).